# MapView not loading contents on Jelly Bean but works on KitKat

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-mapview

Could anyone please tell me any possible reasons why MapView would not load on Jelly Bean 4.1.1 but load perfectly fine on KitKat 4.4.2?

To be a bit more specific:

- I'm using production API key with "Google Maps Android API v2" permission enabled in dev console
- On Jelly Bean the map only shows gray screen within its bounds and a Google logo at the bottom left corner, so the MapView itself is definitely there
- When using Jelly Bean, there are no map tiles on the MapView
- I was able to partially reproduce the bug on KitKat by setting the Android device's date to year 2009, but it loaded the tiles for the map.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I'm banging my head against the wall for a full month now.

Comment: Are you using an actual device? Does the device legitimately have the Play Store and Play Services on it? Does the device's Google Maps app work?

Comment: Yes, I'm using an actual Android devices for both KitKat and Jelly Bean. What do you mean by Play Store services on, I can't find these in the device's settings? Both device's Google Maps app work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this isn't a common problem, but will answer it anyway. Turning off hardware acceleration did the trick, the maps are working now.